# python difference between imported and defined class

Tags: python, class, import

I would like to create dependence between some parameters of instances (not necessarily of the same class as in example). I came up with folowing code, which worked until I decided to move it into module and use it by importing.

```
class objectD(object):
  def __init__(self,val1,val2,val3):
    self.val1 = val1
    self.val2 = val2
    self.val3 = val3

  def __str__(self):
    return str(str(self.val1)+","+str(self.val2)+","+str(self.val3))

  def dependence(self,dependent):
    print "values val1 and val2 of "+str(self)+" now depend on "+dependent
    self.val1 = eval(dependent).val1
    self.val2 = eval(dependent).val2
    self.dependent = dependent

  def update(self):
    self.val1 = eval(self.dependent).val1
    self.val2 = eval(self.dependent).val2

#test
obj1 = objectD(350,4,500)
print obj1
obj2 = objectD(230,1,1000)
print obj2
obj2.dependence("obj1")#problem with imported class occurs there
print obj2
obj1.val1 = 1315
obj1.val2 = 6464
print obj1
obj2.update()
print obj2
```

Problem seems to be in assigning dependence to instance which by using imported version of the class simply does not exist according to python. It seems to me, that calling method dependence() on instance goes on in module and not in my script.
Is there a way to fix the import somehow, or perhaps some different approach to creating dependencies?

Comment: Never, ever use `eval` unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: What "problem"? Are you getting some kind of error message, which you forgot to include? I also don't see any `import` statement in what you posted; how is your question related to importing?

Comment: Also, what are those `eval()` statements supposed to be doing?

Comment: I posted just the version which works to clarify intended funkcionality, if you put the class in a module and import it from there, it won't work anymore.

Comment: eval() statemets should alow for an instance to keep the name of the other instance for the case when the other instance changes its values, so the former instance could be updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no need for `eval`. Why not simply do this instead?

```
class objectD(object):
  def __init__(self,val1,val2,val3):
    self.val1 = val1
    self.val2 = val2
    self.val3 = val3

  def __str__(self):
    return str(str(self.val1)+","+str(self.val2)+","+str(self.val3))

  def dependence(self,dependent):
    print "values val1 and val2 of "+str(self)+" now depend on "+dependent
    self.val1 = dependent.val1
    self.val2 = dependent.val2
    self.dependent = dependent

  def update(self):
    self.val1 = self.dependent.val1
    self.val2 = self.dependent.val2

#test
obj1 = objectD(350,4,500)
print obj1
obj2 = objectD(230,1,1000)
print obj2
obj2.dependence(obj1)#problem with imported class no longer occurs there
print obj2
obj1.val1 = 1315
obj1.val2 = 6464
print obj1
obj2.update()
print obj2
```

This will work as expected, because `dependent` merely stores a reference to `obj1`, not the state of the object itself. So the call to `update()` will actually pull the new values.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tried this, which I absolutely should. Tried some other things though, which let me to the conclusion that it wont be so easy.

Comment: There is one slight issue when the obj1 instance is created again, dependance is lost. I thik I was trying to overcome also this with eval(). Of course it's not big issue, I just have to avoid overwriting instances, which seems to be a bad practice anyway.